# If $f$ is a polynomial of degree $n$, then $f(x) \equiv 0\pmod p$ has at most $n$ solutions.

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory

I know that I have to prove this by induction on $n$ when we let $f(x)=a_{n}x^n + a_{n-1}x^{n-1} +\cdots + a_0$. I have two books in front of me with the complete proof but I don't see how after they assume that the theorem holds for a polynomial of degree $n-1$ and move on to show it holds for a polynomial of degree $n$ they say,

**Either $f(x) \equiv 0\pmod p$ has no solution or at least one solution. If it has no solution the theorem holds (How so? how come is it not also true in the second case?).**

Then they say, suppose that $r$ is a solution. That is $f(r) \equiv 0\pmod p$, and $r$ is a least residue $\pmod p$. Then because $x-r$ is a factor of $x^t -r^t$ for $t=0,1,2\ldots,n$, we have
$$\begin{align*}
f(x)\equiv f(x)-f(r) &\equiv a_{n}(x^n -r^n) + a_{n-1}(x^{n-1} -r^{n-1}) +\cdots + a_0(x -r)\pmod{p}\\
 &\equiv (x-r)g(x)\pmod p
\end{align*}$$
where $g$ is a polynomial of degree $n-1$. suppose that $s$ is also another solution of (1). Thus 
$$f(s) \equiv (s-r)g(s)\equiv0 \pmod p$$
because $p$ is prime it follows that 
$$s\equiv r\pmod p\text{ or }g(s) \equiv 0 \pmod p$$
from the inductions assumption, the second congruence has at most $n-1$ solutions. Since the first congruence has just one solution, the proof is complete.

I would just appreciate is someone could explain the reasoning behind this a little more. Thank you.

Comment: Can you express what part you have issues with? And what those issues are? One thing that I often do when I have issues with a proof is to take the proof idea but ignore the proof, instead trying to write my own proof using the idea.

Comment: @HowardRoark: Use `\pmod{a}` to produce $\pmod{a}$.

Comment: The bold part mainly. How is it that if it has no solutions the theorem holds? Then how come they  decide to use the fact that $x-r$ is a factor of $x^t-r^t$?

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I shall use that from now on. Thanks.

Comment: @Howard: From the fact that $f(x) \equiv 0 \pmod p$ has no solutions, can you prove it has $n$ or fewer solutions?

Comment: Sorry, what is $f$? Is it a polynomial with coefficients in $\mathbf Z$?

Comment: "At most $n$" means $\le n$ solutions, and certainly $0\le n$.

Comment: @DylanMoreland Yes.

Comment: Anyways, the problem seems to be missing something. The degree 0 polynomial $f(x)=p$ has more than 0 roots mod $p$. If you don't like things quite so degenerate, then the degree 1 polynomial $f(x)=px$ has more than 1 root mod $p$. The inductive step is good, but you can't prove the base case from the conditions provided....

Comment: One more thing that is obviously wrong with this question: what is counted must be the _classes modulo $p$_ of solutions to the congruence, not the solutions themeselves, whose number will in general be infinite (unless it is $0$).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Remember that you are trying to prove that the congruence $f(x)\equiv 0\pmod{p}$ has at most $n$ solutions. (*Added.* There must be an assumption that $a_n\not\equiv 0\pmod{p}$ missing, by the way)

The argument is essentially the same one we use to prove that a polynomial of degree $n$ has at most $n$ roots in any field: we do induction on the degree.

> If $f$ is of degree $0$, a nonzero constant, then it has no solutions and we are fine.
>
> Assume the result holds for any polynomial of degree less than $n$, and that $f$ has degree $n\gt 0$. If $f$ has no roots, then we are done: $0$ is less than $n$, so $f$ satisfies the conclusion. If $f$ has at least one root $r$, then we can use the Factor Theorem to write $f(x) = (x-r) g(x)$ for some polynomial $g$ of degree $n-1\lt n$. If $s$ is a root of $f$ different from $r$, then $0 = f(s) = (s-r)g(s)$; since $(s-r)\neq 0$, then $g(s)=0$. That is, all other roots of $f$ come from roots of $g$. By the induction hypothesis, $g$ has at most $n-1$ roots. So $f$ has at most $1+n-1 = n$ roots.
>
> This proves that, whether $f$ has at least one root or no roots, it has at most $n$ roots, proving the result.

The argument here is the same. If $f(x)\equiv 0 \pmod{p}$ has **no** solutions, then you are already done: $0$ is less than $n$. So we can consider the case in which there is at least one solution. It's not that the conclusion will not hold in this latter case (in fact, we will prove it *does*), it's that the conclusion does not immediately follow: from "at least one solution" we cannot immediately conclude "at most $n$ solutions", *whereas* from "no solutions" we **can** immediately conclude "and so at most $n$ (since $0$ is less than $n$)".

Now, we use a lemma:

**Lemma.** Let $r$ be any integer. Then for any nonnegative integer $t$, $x-r$ divides $x^t - r^t$.

*Proof.* Simply note that
$$(x-r)(x^{t-1}+x^{t-2}r+\cdots +xr^{t-2}+r^{t-1}) = x^t-r^t.\quad\Box$$

**Note well:** The fact that $x-r$ divides $x^t-r^t$ does not depend on whether $r$ is a root of $f(x)$ or not: it's a simple algebraic fact. It's **always** true.

Now, if $f(x)$ *does* have roots modulo $p$, then it has at least one; call it $r$. If $f(x)\equiv 0\pmod{p}$ has at least one root $r$, then we have $f(r)\equiv 0\pmod{p}$. We have
$$\begin{align*}
f(x) &\equiv f(x) - 0\pmod{p}\\
&\equiv f(x) -f(r)\pmod{p}\\
&\equiv a_nx^n + \cdots + a_0 - (a_nr^n +\cdots + a_0)
\pmod{p}\\
&\equiv a_n(x^n - r^n) + a_{n-1}(x^{n-1}-r^{n-1}) + \cdots + a_1(x-r) + (a_0-a_0)\pmod{p}
\end{align*}$$
Now, by the Lemma, $(x-r)$ divides each of $x^n-r^n$, $x^{n-1}-r^{n-1},\ldots,x-r$. So $x-r$ divides 
$$a_n(x^n-r^n)+a_{n-1}(x^{n-1}-r^{n-1}) + \cdots + a_1(x-r).$$
(This argument takes the place of the Factor Theorem in the case above).

The conclusion is that if $f(r)\equiv 0\pmod{n}$, then we can write 
$$f(x) \equiv (x-r)g(x)\pmod{p}$$
for some polynomial $g(x)$ with integer coefficients. Now the argument proceeds as in the real case: if $f(s)\equiv 0\pmod{p}$, then $(s-r)g(s)\equiv 0 \pmod{p}$, so $g(s)\equiv 0\pmod{p}$. So any *other* root of $f$ gives a root of $g$, and since $g$ has at most $n-1$ roots modulo $p$, then $f$ has at most $1+(n-1)=n$ roots modulo $p$.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH! This is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 3):

The idea of the proof is simple. If $\,f(x) = (x\!-\!r)g(x)\,$ has $\,n\!+\!1 > \deg f\,$ roots then, as shown, the $\,n\,$ roots of $\,f\,$ different from $\,r\,$ are all roots of $\,g,\,$ so $\,g\,$ has $\,n > \deg g\, (= \deg(f)\!-\!1)\,$ roots, contra the induction hypothesis (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2049882/242) for full details, and generalizations).

The proof essentially shows "additivity" of roots, i.e. $\,{\rm roots}(fg) = {\rm roots}(f) \cup {\rm roots}(g),\,$ which is true precisely because $\,\Bbb Z/p\,$ is a domain, i.e. $\, a,b\not\equiv 0\,\Rightarrow\,ab\not\equiv 0,\,$ i.e. no zero divisors exist (else it fails, e.g. $\!\bmod 8\!:\,  (x\!-\!1)(x\!+\!1)\,$ has root $\,x\equiv3\,$ which is neither a root of $\,x\!-\!1\,$ nor $\,x\!+\!1.$

More structurally: $\, a_i\ne a_j\in D\,$ a domain $\Rightarrow\ x-a_i\ $ are nonassociate primes in $\,D[x],\,$ since $\, D[x]/(x\!-\!a) \cong D\,$ is a domain. So $\,  x\!-\!a_1, \ldots, x\!-\!a_n\ |\ f(x) \Rightarrow  (x\!-\!a_1)\cdots (x\!-\!a_n)\ |\ f(x)\ $ by [LCM = product for nonassociate primes.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1982395/242). Comparing degrees yields a contradiction if $\, n > \deg f.$

Answer (score 2):

Another way of proving this that you might like better: Given a polynomial $f \in \mathbb Z[x]$ we can reduce its coefficients modulo $p$ to obtain an element $\bar f$ of $\mathbb F_p[x]$, where $\mathbb F_p = \mathbb Z/(p)$ is the field with $p$ elements. The result you now want to use is that a polynomial of degree $n \geq 0$ over a field has at most $n$ roots.

To prove *that*, use induction on $n$ and the division theorem as proved in [these notes](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/ringtheory/divthm.pdf). To give more detail: if $f$ has a root $a$ then apply the division theorem to $f(x)$ and $x - a$.

[Note that you want to use the degree of the reduced polynomial. The integral polynomial $f(x) = p$, for example, has degree $0$, and yet it has $p$ zeros modulo $p$. Also note that it's important for $\mathbb F_p$ to be a field — the polynomial $2x$ has two roots in $\mathbb Z/(4)$, for example.]

Comment: This is a bit sketchy — will try to fill it in later. Dog needs to walk.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time!